# Twig - multiple if conditions inside a foreach loop

Tags: php, twig, silex

I'm coding up a twig template to display a grid containing 'sector' objects in a simple HTML table. If the object has no link adjacent to the left I want to start a new row, if it has no next link i want to end the row.

The strange thing about this code sample is the output, all is looking good except 0 should be being output on the same row as the sequence 1,2,3..

var_dump'ing the Sector object shows that it has a 'next' link so the closing tr shouldn't be being rendered. Calling the hasNext function on this object returns true and outputting the hasNext function within the template shows true.

```
0
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19
20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29
30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39
40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49
50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59
60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69
70  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79
80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89
90  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99
```

Here's the template:

```
<table>
    {% for sector in sectors %}

        {% if sector.hasPrev() == false %}
            <tr>
        {% endif %}

        <td>{{ sector.Id }}</td>

        {% if sector.hasNext() == false %}
            </tr>
        {% endif %}

    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

hasNext and hasPrev functions are defined as:

```
public function hasNext(){
    return in_array($this->_id + 1, $this->_links);
}

public function hasPrev(){
    return in_array($this->_id - 1, $this->_links);
}
```

and the sector object (0) var_dumped is:

```
array (size=100)
  0 => 
    object(App\Model\Sector)[62]
      private '_id' => int 0
      private '_links' => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => int 1
          1 => int 10
          2 => int 11
      private '_universe' => null
```

This happens even if I add the kludge 'and sector.Id > 0', thinking this might either be a limitation of twig or an RTM moment...

Any help appreciated, cheers

Comment: Can you please append the resulting HTML code and also the definitions of `.hasPrev()` and `.hasNext()`?

Comment: In your hasNext() and hasPrev(), is it not the key you want to check for not the value? so try using array_key_exists function instead

Comment: Nah, it's the value I'm looking for (1,10,11 in the above example). Also, the function returns the expected value it seems as though twig just isn't evaluating it properly

Comment: in that case maybe just change the return value from the functions to be 1 or 0 to see if its related to evaluating "true" "false"

Comment: Can you also give the sector `1`?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Ninsuo's comment I managed to figure this out.

I was viewing the markup in chrome developer tools which showed a closing TR after cell 0 leading me to believe that the second condition was being triggered...

In actual fact developer tools looks like it 'fixes' malformed html in the element inspector. Viewing the source directly showed that the closing TR wasn't being added (expected output) and in fact it was the opening tr for cell 1 that was triggering the new row because there was no backlink to cell 0.

```
1 => 
  object(App\Model\Sector)[66]
    private '_id' => int 1
    private '_links' => 
      array (size=5)
        0 => int 1
        1 => int 2
        2 => int 10
        3 => int 11
        4 => int 12
```